# Change or-filter into and-filter for joined table's `column = ANY()` comparison

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, filter, postgresql-9.5

So I have a table of users and another table of their hobbies. I've created a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    usr.id,
    usr.name,
    usr.gender
FROM usr
LEFT JOIN hobby ON hobby.usr_id = usr.id
WHERE %(hobbies)s IS NULL OR hobby.id = ANY(%(hobbies)s)
```

Which I call by passing in a value to `%(hobbies)s`: either `NULL` if no hobby filters were provided, or a list of hobby IDs to be used as filters.

This works, but it ends up being an "or" filter to select the users based on their hobbies. For example, if `hobbies = [<football_id>, <basketball_id>]`, it's enough that the user has *either* football *or* basketball as his hobby.

What I'd like to have is the above but where the user is required to have *all* of the hobbies provided in the `%(hobbies)s` list. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use array

for example compare arrays:

```
select array[1,2,3] = array[1,2,3]; // TRUE
select array[1,2,3] = array[1,2,5]; // FALSE
```

And contains array in other array:

```
select ARRAY[1,4,3] @> ARRAY[3,1] // TRUE
select ARRAY[1,4,3] @> ARRAY[1,2,4] // FALSE
```

And your query:

```
SELECT
    usr.id,
    usr.name,
    usr.gender
FROM usr
where (select array(select h.id from hobby h where h.usr_id = usr.id)) @> (select array[1,2,3])
```

Comment: Hmm but this wouldn't work if the user had additional hobbies which aren't required by the filter, right? It would end up as `array[1, 2, 3] = array[1, 2]`, which results into false even though the user had both required hobbies

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen i fortget on this scenario but you can use this ARRAY[1,4,3] @> ARRAY[3,1]

Comment: Oh nice! This also mean it no longer needs to be ordered then? Update your answer with that additional `@>` method and I'll accept :)